# How to databind to onTextChanged for an EditText on Android?

Tags: android, android-databinding

In [Yigit Boyar and George Mount's talk on Android Databinding](https://realm.io/news/data-binding-android-boyar-mount/) they illustrate how easy it is to bind to `TextWatcher`'s `onTextChanged` (at 13:41). On a Button. Are their slides wrong? First of all the `Button` View doesn't have an `onTextChanged` property. It neither has a `setOnTextChanged` method. Neither does `EditText`. But they both have `addTextChangedListener` which takes a `TextWatcher` as input.

So what are they talking about? How do they do it? Their example code does not compile, but gives this error:

```
Error:(17) No resource identifier found for attribute 'onTextChanged' in package 'android'
```

How do I bind to a "Text Changed Event" on any View, or EditText in particular, with the Android Databinding framework?

Comment: The Yigit video link is showing only images of them talking. You can't tell what is happening.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Actually it works out of the box. I think my mistake was using an old version of the data binding framework. Using the latest, this is the procedure:

View:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:text="Enter username:"
    android:onTextChanged="@{data.onTextChanged}" />
```

Model:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    Log.w("tag", "onTextChanged " + s);
}
```

Make also sure that you have assigned **model** into **DataBinding**

For ex. in your activity

```
lateinit var activityMainDataBinding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activityMainDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main) 
    val dataViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DataViewModel::class.java)
    activityMainDataBinding.dataModel = dataViewModel
}
```

Make sure you are referncing gradle build tools v1.5.0 or higher and have enabled databinding with `android.dataBinding.enabled true` in your build.gradle.

**edit:** Functioning demo project [here](https://github.com/Nilzor/mvp-to-mvvm-transition/tree/twoway-explicit). [view](https://github.com/Nilzor/mvp-to-mvvm-transition/blob/twoway-explicit/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_login.xml#L130). [model](https://github.com/Nilzor/mvp-to-mvvm-transition/blob/twoway-explicit/app/src/main/java/com/nilzor/presenterexample/viewmodels/LoginFragmentViewModel.java#L88).

Comment: This solution does not work. EditText does not have an onTextChanged attribute.

Comment: @M.Palsich it just works. https://news.realm.io/news/data-binding-android-boyar-mount/

Comment: Yeah EditText doesn't need an onTextChanged attribute because it is defined as a BindingAdapter: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/android-6.0.0_r7/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/TextViewBindingAdapter.java#299 . tl;dr: Data binding is magic.

Comment: is there a way to act on the edittext in the onTextChanged method? for example let's say that I want to change the text color.

Comment: Sure, just bind `android:textColor` to an `ObservableInt` and update that value from `onTextChanged` in the ViewModel

Comment: This does not work, just tried it. Don't know how it was accepted or how any of you got it to work

Comment: @clementiano: Added link to functioning github project in the answer. Most likely you have the wrong signature on your method.

Comment: So I'm new to data binding in Android Studio and I follow your example in project and it didn't work. After searching and searching and searching, I found out that I should set the viewmodel to the variable like this `binding.setData(myViewModel);`. It is `setData` because I named the viewmodel's variable as `data` in my xml, like this `<variable name="data"  type=".viewmodel.MyViewModel"/>`. Then it worked. Anyway thank you very much man, this really helps.

Comment: @Nilzor your this line helps me Make also sure that you have assigned model into DataBinding :D

Comment: The best solution is the bellow from @Khemraj Sharma. That is what written in Android Developer site

Answer (score 66):

To extend @Nilzors answer, it is also possible to pass text and/or other parameters in the layout:

**View:**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:text="Enter username:"
    android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.onUsernameTextChanged(text)}" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public void onUsernameTextChanged(CharSequence text) {
    // TODO do something with text
}
```

You always need to pass either zero or all parameters.

Comment: Does not work! It says onTextChanged is not an attribute

Comment: If you've setup databinding properly in your project, then you have some binding adapters already prepared and this is one of them. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/android-6.0.0_r7/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/TextViewBindingAdapter.java#299 and see other comments bellow @Nilzor's answer.

Comment: how to write this for afterTextChange method ? I don't want to pass any data to method, I'll fetch text from LiveData itself.

Answer (score 44):

### The Easy Way

If you are using `onTextChange()` to **update text in the model** then you can use [Two-way Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002616/6891563) directly.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.package.User"/>
</data>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={user.name}"/>
```

The model class will have a `getter` and `setter`:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now the `name` in the model will be changed in realtime with user interaction. So using `binding.getUser().getName()` will get the latest text.

**One-Way Binding** will only gets updated when model value is changed. It does not update model back real time.

```
android:text="@{user.name}"
```

**Two-Way Binding** update model variable in real time with user input.

```
android:text="@={user.name}"
```

**The ONLY difference** is of `=` (equal sign) [receives data changes to the property and listen to user updates at the same time](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way).

Comment: yes. This is the easiest solution !! working as expected! I hope people scroll down and look at this answer !!

Comment: This won't work, unless you are okay with extraneous callbacks happening.

Comment: How can I print name when it's changed?

Comment: it worked with me .. Thanks @Khemraj , you might need to use livedata     val name = MutableLiveData("") then name.observeForever {
            /*you code here to listen to changes*/
        }

Comment: As i expect, That is

Comment: @Khemraj, but how can I get immediate data when I start to write in edittext

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit Your data will be captured in user.name as showed in above example.

Comment: This is the official solution. this should be accepted answer

Answer (score 12):

If you just need `text` parameter after text has changed, you could use `android:afterTextChanged` binding adapter. for example:

```
android:afterTextChanged="@{(text) -> viewModel.onTextChange(text)}"
```

Then in your `ViewModel` just implement like this:

```
fun onTextChange(editable: Editable?) {
    Log.d("TAG","New text: ${editable.toString()}")
}
```

Furthermore, there is `android:beforeTextChanged` which used to know old text before text change event, usage is same as `android:afterTextChanged`.

Answer (score 6):

Im using this method to handle on text change listener in android databinding.1st in your **ViewModel** class create **LiveData** variable, And also create **getText** method which returns **LiveData** object.

- `public MutableLiveData<String> verifyCodes = new MutableLiveData<>();`
- `public LiveData<String> getCodes(){
      return verifyCodes;
  }`

---

Then in your xml files **editText** field set attribute on **text** bind with above liveData field

- `<EditText
   android:id="@+id/et_verification1st"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:text="@={viewModel.verifyCodes}"/>`

In databinding you already know how to create variable of viewModel class inside data tag i beleive.As example

- `<data>
      <variable
          name="viewModel"
          type="viewModel.VerifyUserActivityViewModel" />
  </data>`

---

Ok now your **activity** you have to **observe** liveData object we created inside viewModel class

- `mViewModel.getCodes().observe(this,new Observer< String>(){
  @Override
  public void onChange(String strings){
  log.d("OnChange",strings);
  }});`

You can perform any logic when text changing inside **onChange** method

Comment: Doesn't your approach come at the expense of exposing a MutableLiveData to the Acitivity/Fragment?

Answer (score 5):

**1. In your BindingAdapter class, write down this. Here I have passed viewModel so that we can do particular task against particular viewModel:**

```
@BindingAdapter("app:addTextChangeListener")
fun addTextChangeListener(view: EditText, viewModel: ViewModel) {

    view.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            when (viewModel) {
                is LoginViewModel -> viewModel.invisibleErrorTexts()
            }
        }

    })

}
```

**2. In your XML, in the Edittext, put the attribute given below:
Here "viewModel" is the variable name of the LoginViewModel in my layout tag**

```
app:addTextChangeListener="@{viewModel}"
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it working like this:

Fragment:

```
    class DiAtomicMoleculesFragment : Fragment() {
        private lateinit var binding: FragmentDiatomicMoleculesBinding
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            binding = FragmentDiatomicMoleculesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
            return binding.root
        }
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            val recyclerAdapter = DiAtomicMoleculesAdapter(onClickListener)
    
            binding.diRecyclerView.apply {
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
                adapter = recyclerAdapter
            }
    
            val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DiAtomicMoleculesViewModel::class.java)
            viewModel.getDiAtomicMoleculesByName().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { items ->
                recyclerAdapter.setData(items)
            })
    
            //this is important !!!!!!!!!!!!!
            binding.viewModel = viewModel
        }
    }
```

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.mychemistry.viewmodel.DiAtomicMoleculesViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/di_search_box"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.onTextChange(text)}"/>

<!--     or this ->      android:afterTextChanged="@{(e) -> viewModel.onTextChange(e)}"/>-->

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/di_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/di_search_box" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

ViewModel:

```
class DiAtomicMoleculesViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val allLiveData = AppDatabase.getInstance().getDiAtomicMoleculeDao().getAll()
    private val filterLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val searchByLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(filterLiveData, ::filter)

    fun getDiAtomicMolecules(): LiveData<List<DiAtomicMolecule>> {
        return allLiveData
    }

    private fun filter(text: String): LiveData<List<DiAtomicMolecule>> {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance().getDiAtomicMoleculeDao().find(text)
    }

    fun getDiAtomicMoleculesByName(): LiveData<List<DiAtomicMolecule>> {
        return searchByLiveData
    }

    fun onTextChange(e: Editable?) {
        filterLiveData.value = e?.toString()
    }

    fun onTextChange(text: CharSequence?) {
        filterLiveData.value = text?.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. create a class (I named him BindingAdapters). Then define your bindingAdapter methods.

   ```
   @BindingAdapter("app:textChangedListener")
   fun onTextChanged(et: EditText, number: Int) {
   et.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
       override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
           if (et.text.toString().trim().length >= number) {
               et.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
           }
       }

       override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
       override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
   })
   ```

   }
2. set this attr for editText in xml layout

   ```
   <EditText
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:textChangedListener="@{3}" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

the best way for this is adding bind adapter and a text watcher.

```
public class Model{
    private TextWatcher textWatcher;

public Model(){
        this.textWatcher= getTextWatcherIns();
}

private TextWatcher getTextWatcherIns() {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //do some thing
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //do some thing

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //do some thing
            }
        };
    }

    public TextWatcher getTextWatcher() {
        return textWatcher;
    }

    public void setTextWatcher(TextWatcher textWatcher) {
        this.textWatcher = textWatcher;
    }

    @BindingAdapter("textChangedListener")
    public static void bindTextWatcher(EditText editText, TextWatcher textWatcher) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }
}
```

and in your xml add this attr to your edit text

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:textChangedListener="@{model.textWatcher}" />
```

Comment: ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null in class SpotFragmentBindingImpl. A BindingAdapter in com.mytrain.findmytrain.ui.viewmodel.SpotViewmodel is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.

Comment: @ABDULRAHMAN your BindingAdapter method is not static.Am I right?

Answer (score -7):

Attach an `setOnFocusChangeListener` to the `EditText`, and use compare the textual content with a global variable (of the previous state/content of the field) to determine whether it has changed:

```
    mEditTextTitle.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
                // check if text has changed       
        }
    });
```

Comment: At least, that's a way to *achieve* "onTextChanged", but that's not exactly what you're asking. My solution only fires when the user actually *leaves* the EditText.