# What are parameters of EdiText android:onValueChange

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

#### Orignal Question

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onValueChange="@{handler.passwordValidator}"
    android:text="@={model.password}"/>
```

I could not find parameters of `android:onValueChange`. What should I put in below method parameters?

```
public void passwordValidator() {

}
```

- I tried to pass empty method to this attribute, thought that logs will tell me its arguments, but I could not get that.
- I could not find it in [EditText Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText).
- [Google search results](https://www.google.co.in/search?ei=CZegW9XSPIjavAT9rIjwCA&q=edittext%20onvlauechange%20&oq=edittext%20onvlauechange%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1l2.158455.160150.0.160386.14.9.0.0.0.0.253.598.0j1j2.3.0..2..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..11.3.593...0j0i20i263k1j0i13i5i10i30k1.0.MyX2-xC2KXQ)  does not contain any information about this.

#### Tried many possible parameters cases

`android:onValueChange="@{handler.passwordValidator}"`

`android:onValueChange="@{handler::passwordValidator}"`

`android:onValueChange="@{()->handler.passwordValidator()}"`

`android:onValueChange="@{(v)->handler.passwordValidator()}"`

`android:onValueChange="@{(view, value) ->handler.passwordValidator()}"`

Also please tell a way to find parameters of any attribute, so that I can find myself.

**Please note, It is not related to `android:onTextChanged`.**

#### Update 1

@Tenten I got this in suggestions.

[image: suggestion]

#### Update 2 (I thinnk, It is not IDE bug)

It can not be bug of Android because when you put unknown attribute then error comes after compilation.

**Case 1 (unknown attribute)**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:asdf=""
    android:text="@={model.password}"/>
```

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: attribute
>   \u0027android:asdf\u0027 not
>   found.","sources":[{"file":"E:\AndroidWorkspace\RawSamples\Sample\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml","position":{"startLine":23}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

**Case 2 (using `android:onValueChange`)**

Error is changed in this case, if there is no `android:onValueChange` attribute then error should be same.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onValueChange="@{handler::passwordValidator}"
    android:text="@={model.password}"/>
```

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not resolve
>   >     handler::passwordValidator as a listener.
>   >     file:E:\AndroidWorkspace\RawSamples\Sample\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
>   >     loc:23:37 - 23:62   ****\ data binding error ****

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798426/how-to-databind-to-ontextchanged-for-an-edittext-on-android

Comment: @NileshRathod Hi ,I could not see `onValueChange` in this question.

Comment: Where did you get the attribute onValueChange? It seems that there's no onValueChange method on EditText.

Comment: @Khemraj hm, but also you can see from the screenshot that there's no documentation for it, maybe just a bug of android studio. What are you trying to do? Maybe you can use onTextChanged if you want to get the text.

Comment: It's IDE's issue, that show you one of properties of android name space, take it easy

Comment: @TentenPonce See update part of question.

Comment: @TentenPonce there is no documentation of `android:onTextChanged` too. you can check it. Press ctrl + Q in `onTextChanged` block.

Comment: Hm, its weird, I've also checked up to the `TextView` which is extended by the `EditText` but there's no `onValueChange` too...

Comment: @TentenPonce This is stupid question. This attribute is related to NumberPicker. I am deleting this question. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener, Sorry to take your time :D, this is really an IDE issue, that It can not filter attributes related to only EditText.

Comment: @TentenPonce It says `You can not delete this question, as others have invested time`, it respects your all time. :D, no worries my profile will have 1 stupid question as well.

Comment: Ahahaha, that's why I do have trust issues on android studio on XML part :DD

Answer (score 0):

replace :

```
"@{handler.passwordValidator()}"
```

with

```
"@{handler::passwordValidator}"
```

also make following method non-static

```
public void passwordValidator(View view) {

}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it is not related to my question.

Comment: as far as I know edittext does not have onValueChange property. you may use onTextChange, but not as tag property, you have to do it programmatically...

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
EditText myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextBox);
myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
  int count, int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
  int before, int count) {
    passwordValidator(s.toString());
 }
});
```

And this

```
public void passwordValidator(String password) {

}
```

Comment: It can be an alternative, but my question was for `onValueChange`, Also I will prefer `android:onTextChange` instead of your solution.