# Two-way binding: how to format currency TextWatcher on EditText?

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack

My model is extend of **androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel** not **BaseObservable**:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val price:String? = null
}
```

XML:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={viewModel.price}"/>
```

Activity:

```
val binding: ActivityMainBinding = ...
binding.viewModel = viewModel 
binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
```

Is there any way to apply textwatcher to format currency in real time when user typing number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to databind to onTextChanged for an EditText on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798426/how-to-databind-to-ontextchanged-for-an-edittext-on-android)

Comment: @sonnet it is not since my model is extend of androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel not BaseObservable

Comment: Where did you see a reference to `BaseObservable`? Please try out the solutions from that link first.

Comment: The solution on that link are for the model based on BaseObservable not androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

Comment: Try this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#converters

Comment: @Yamashiro Rion Thanks for comment. I just tried and it does not work in this case.

Comment: It's tempting to implement this with databindings, but I'd rather suggest to create a custom component or configuration to handle the formatting within the view directly. Have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter

Answer (score 0):

create a formatter which takes value of EditText

```
object Converter {
    @InverseMethod("formatCurrency")
    fun format(
        view: EditText, oldValue: Long,
        value: Long
    ): String {
        // Converts long to String.
    }
}
```

and then create a **bindable text** or `LiveData` which keeps text of EditText by getting it from `TextWatcher`.

```
android:text="@={Converter.formatCurrency(viewmodel.yourCurrentText)}"
```

Comment: I got error: cannot find method formatCurrency(java.lang.String) in class xx.util.Converter

Comment: you need to import this Converter class in your xml

Comment: or you can change Converter's method name accordingly